# How to add class to image tag in Twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

How can I add a CSS class to an `<img>` tag by using a template file if output looks like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap/templates/system/image.html.twig' -->
<img class="media__image media__element b-lazy b-responsive img-responsive b-loaded" src="/sites/default/files/styles/media_image/public/2018-03/Trainer-Norbert-Sauer-auf-der-Rennbahn-Wambel-Am-Donnerstag-249903.jpg?h=c913b3c6&amp;itok=sENPOWtc" alt="Trainer Norbert Sauer auf der Rennbahn Wambel">
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/contrib/bootstrap/templates/system/image.html.twig' -->
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hook_preprocess_field` to add classes to the attributes array without modifying twig:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['entity_type'] == 'media' && $variables['field_name'] == 'image') {
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
      $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#item_attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I am checking by both entity type (media) here along with the field name (image).

If you want to do this by image style, you can also use `hook_preprocess_image`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_image().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['style_name'] == 'content_embed') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
  }
}
```

In both cases you do not need to touch the Twig file because the image field will be rendered and as long as `attributes` is output on the img tag (coming from core, it will be), the class will be appended to any other existing classes.

Comment: Any other solution rather than preprocess? Like using merge in attribute?

Comment: Like this `{% set user_pic = author.picture.thumbnail %}
        {% set user_pic = user_pic|merge({"#attributes" : {'class' : 'rounded-circle'} }) %}
        {{ user_pic }}`

Answer (score 0):

Copy `image.html.twig` from `themes/contrib/bootstrap/templates/system/image.html.twig` to your theme's template folder

and modify the image tag adding `addClass("myClass")`

```
<img{{ attributes.addClass(classes).addClass("myClass") }} />
```

**Note:** this will apply the class to all images fields in the site

Comment: Note that this will apply the class to all images uploaded to image fields in the site.

Comment: @Kevin yes I know, it seems this is what the poster actually wants ... unless I am wrong ;-)

Comment: The heading is misleading. Actually I like to add a class to the IMG tag of a given field called field--trainer--photo

Comment: Misleading or not, it contributes to solve the initial question. I agree it's not the best answer, but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A less hacky option is to enable Display Suite field templates, which allows you to add classes to the immediately `<div>` wrapper of the `<img>` tag. This way, you can practically add different classes to different image fields.

Comment: Display Suite is a heavy dependency though if you aren't really using it for much else - and it will also change how preprocess hooks etc are invoked. If you already have a healthy .theme file going, it might break things unexpectedly.

Comment: I didn’t downvote it.